# Do codes that rely on cursor position still work in virtual machine

Tags: virtual-machine, pyautogui

I've got no idea how virtual machines work, would pyautogui code that moves mouse to a certain pixel on screen still work with a virtual machine? I want to have my code that clicks on my screen to join google meet to be able to run without my PC being on.

Answer (score 0):

Answering whether this will work or not is a non-trivial question.

Below are some of the gotcha's I had to deal with when I was running pyautogui tests against a test VM.

If your VM isn't rendering a UI then pyautogui won't run correctly. Generally, to save resources a VM will only render the UI when it needs to display the UI.

If your tests were developed on a system with a different resolution than the VM there are a whole host of bugs that can be introduced. Changes in resolution can result in target images no longer being valid due to UI scaling and changes in layout. Any hard coded positions or calculated pixel offsets can also be broken if the resolution changes. Best practice is to develop your code in as close an environment to the one it will be run in as possible.

I would consider pyautogui an automation solution of last resort. If you've exhausted other automation options, then the best way to know if it will work is to start small with a proof of concept against your environment. Then slowly expand automation capabilities as you work through the many quirks associated with it's testing paradigm.